# How do I iterate over a HashSet while simultaneously updating it in Rust?

Tags: parsing, rust, containers, hashset

In most languages, iterating over a container while simultaneously mutating it is a glaring anti-pattern. In Rust, the borrow checker makes it impossible.

But there are cases where this is needed. An example is Earley's algorithm for parsing. I'm new to Rust and I'm not aware of a known good way to iterate over a `HashSet` (or in fact any container) while extending it. I came up with the following (generalized from the Earley use case):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn extend_from_within<T, F>(original: &mut HashSet<T>, process: F) 
    where T: std::cmp::Eq,
          T: std::hash::Hash,
          F: Fn(&T) -> Set<T>
{
    let mut curr : HashSet<T> = HashSet::new(); // Items currently being processed
    let mut next : HashSet<T> = HashSet::new(); // New items

    // go over the original set once
    let hack : &HashSet<T> = original; // &mut HashSet is not an iterator
    for x in hack {
        for y in process(x) {
            if !original.contains(&y) {
                curr.insert(y);
            }
        }
    }

    // Process and extend until no new items emerge
    while !curr.is_empty() {
        for x in &curr {
            for y in process(x) {
                // make sure that no item is processed twice
                // the check on original is redundant, but might save space
                if !curr.contains(&y) && !original.contains(&y) {
                    next.insert(y);
                }
            }
        }

        original.extend(curr.drain());
        std::mem::swap(&mut curr, &mut next);
    }
}
```

As you see, any call to process can yield multiple items. They are all added to the set and all of them have to be processed as well, but only if they haven't been seen. This works well enough.  But keeping up to 4 sets, doing 3 checks for membership on each item (one of them twice on the original array) seems ridiculous for this problem. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you precise what kind of mutations you want ? Mutations of the values ? Entry removals ? Entry additions ?

Comment: Entry addition.

Comment: A hash set, whatever the language, is, by structure, unfit for mixing iterations and additions as there's no intrinsic order which isn't broken by additions. You seem to be starting with the wrong collection (or wrong content)

Comment: I see. I'm not at all committed to the hash set, but I need unique elements. Concretely, I', using a struct of four usize integers as items (members of the set), in case that's relevant.
What other options are there? Sorted vectors?

Comment: I won't dive deeper, as I don't have time to study the algorithm but as your struct can be made Copy, you can probably just combine a hashset to check unicity and a vecdeque acting as a queue. Having Copy elements makes everything easier here, no need for just a unique collection.

Comment: What I do sometimes is, while iterating, adding the new elements to a temporary `Vec`; then, when the iteration finishes, I extend the map with the data from the temporary `Vec` and repeat if needed.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not aware of a known good way to iterate over a HashSet (or in fact any Container) while extending it

I think there's mostly three patterns for handling modifications while iterating over `HashMaps`/`HashSets`:

- Collecting the modifications into a `Vec` and applying them after the iteration
- `drain`ing the `HashSet` and `collect`ing into a new one
- `retain`, but that's for deletions only

But your case is special anyway, you want to saturate your set with `process`, right?

> Is there a better way?

In this case, I might go for

```
let mut todo = original.iter().map(Clone::clone).collect::<VecDeque<T>>();
while let Some(x) = todo.pop_front() {
    for x in process(&x) {
        if original.insert(x.clone()) {
            todo.push_back(x);
        }
    }
}
```

- The `VecDeque` is probably not necessary (a normal `Vec` would do), unless you have some requirement on the order of processing elements. Cache-wise, a `Vec` may be better.
- One could avoid the `clone`s by instead keeping the `Set` result of `process(x)` in `todo`. Without knowing what `Set` and `T` are, I can't say which is better. If the result of `process` is often empty, this would also allow to filter out empties before pushing them onto `todo`.
- [Edit:] Another variant may be to

  ```
  let mut todo = original
      .iter()
      .flat_map(&process)
      .filter(|x| !original.contains(x))
      .collect::<VecDeque<T>>();
  todo.iter().for_each(|x| {
      original.insert(x.clone());
  });
  // while let …
  ```

  This might allocate less, but cause more hash map accesses / cache misses. Finding which variant is more efficient really requires benchmarking.